# Get the last records of KStream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I'm very new to Kafka Stream API.
I have a KStream like this:

```
    KStream<Long,String> joinStream = builder.stream(("output"));
```

The KStream with records value look like this:
[image]

The stream will be updated every 1s.
I need to build a Rest API that will be calculated based on the value profit and spotPrice.
But I've struggled to get the value of the last record.

Comment: what do you mean by "last record"? if you are processing a stream the values are continually coming. Maybe you want to transform a value profit and spotPrice into another value? Or do you want to aggregate multiple profit values and spot prices and calculate the average in a time window?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you mean the `max` value of the stream when you say the `last value` as the values are continuously arriving. Then you can use the `reduce` transformation to always update the output stream with the max value.

```
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<Long, String> stream = builder.stream("INPUT_TOPIC", Consumed.with(Serdes.Long(), Serdes.String()));
stream
      .mapValues(value -> Long.valueOf(value))
      .groupByKey()
      .reduce(new Reducer<Long>() {
            @Override
            public Long apply(Long currentMax, Long v) {
                  return (currentMax > v) ? currentMax : v;
              }
      })
      .toStream().to("OUTPUT_TOPIC");
return builder.build();
```

And in case that you want to retrive it in a rest api i suggest to take a look at Spring cloud + Kafka streams (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html) that you can exchange messages to spring web.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. Let me clarify the requirement: I have a joined stream which joins from 2 streams retrieve data from an API which I will retrieve every 1s. I want to build an API to return data which retrieve from that joined stream.